Вывод нажатой клавиши в консоль. GLFW, C++
Можно ли как-то вывести в консоль нажатую клавишу(в формате строки, а не int)? Максимум нашел способ: через switch искать нужную клавишу. Если знаете способ проще, напишите пожалуйста.
Вот что у меня получилось:
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

std::string getKeyName(int key)
{
switch (key)
{
case GLFW_KEY_SPACE:
    return "Space";

case GLFW_KEY_APOSTROPHE:
    return "'";
case GLFW_KEY_COMMA:
    return ",";
case GLFW_KEY_MINUS:
    return "-";
case GLFW_KEY_PERIOD:
    return ".";
case GLFW_KEY_SLASH:
    return "/";

case GLFW_KEY_0:
    return "0";
case GLFW_KEY_1:
    return "1";
case GLFW_KEY_2:
    return "2";
case GLFW_KEY_3:
    return "3";
case GLFW_KEY_4:
    return "4";
case GLFW_KEY_5:
    return "5";
case GLFW_KEY_6:
    return "6";
case GLFW_KEY_7:
    return "7";
case GLFW_KEY_8:
    return "8";
case GLFW_KEY_9:
    return "9";

case GLFW_KEY_SEMICOLON:
    return ";";
case GLFW_KEY_EQUAL:
    return "=";

case GLFW_KEY_A:
    return "A";
case GLFW_KEY_B:
    return "B";
case GLFW_KEY_C:
    return "C";
case GLFW_KEY_D:
    return "D";
case GLFW_KEY_E:
    return "E";
case GLFW_KEY_F:
    return "F";
case GLFW_KEY_G:
    return "G";
case GLFW_KEY_H:
    return "H";
case GLFW_KEY_I:
    return "I";
case GLFW_KEY_J:
    return "J";
case GLFW_KEY_K:
    return "K";
case GLFW_KEY_L:
    return "L";
case GLFW_KEY_M:
    return "M";
case GLFW_KEY_N:
    return "N";
case GLFW_KEY_O:
    return "O";
case GLFW_KEY_P:
    return "P";
case GLFW_KEY_Q:
    return "Q";
case GLFW_KEY_R:
    return "R";
case GLFW_KEY_S:
    return "S";
case GLFW_KEY_T:
    return "T";
case GLFW_KEY_U:
    return "U";
case GLFW_KEY_V:
    return "V";
case GLFW_KEY_W:
    return "W";
case GLFW_KEY_X:
    return "X";
case GLFW_KEY_Y:
    return "Y";
case GLFW_KEY_Z:
    return "Z";

case GLFW_KEY_LEFT_BRACKET:
    return "[";
case GLFW_KEY_BACKSLASH:
    return "\\";
case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT_BRACKET:
    return "]";
case GLFW_KEY_GRAVE_ACCENT:
    return "`";
case GLFW_KEY_WORLD_1:
    return "non-US #1";
case GLFW_KEY_WORLD_2:
    return "non-US #2";
case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE:
    return "Escape";
case GLFW_KEY_ENTER:
    return "Enter";
case GLFW_KEY_TAB:
    return "Tab";
case GLFW_KEY_BACKSPACE:
    return "Backspace";
case GLFW_KEY_INSERT:
    return "Insert";
case GLFW_KEY_DELETE:
    return "Delete";
case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT:
    return "Right";
case GLFW_KEY_LEFT:
    return "Left";
case GLFW_KEY_DOWN:
    return "Down";
case GLFW_KEY_UP:
    return "Up";
case GLFW_KEY_PAGE_UP:
    return "PageUp";
case GLFW_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
    return "PageDown";
case GLFW_KEY_HOME:
    return "Home";
case GLFW_KEY_END:
    return "End";
case GLFW_KEY_CAPS_LOCK:
    return "CapsLock";
case GLFW_KEY_SCROLL_LOCK:
    return "ScrollLock";
case GLFW_KEY_NUM_LOCK:
    return "NumLock";
case GLFW_KEY_PRINT_SCREEN:
    return "PrintScreen";
case GLFW_KEY_PAUSE:
    return "Pause";

case GLFW_KEY_F1:
    return "F1";
case GLFW_KEY_F2:
    return "F2";
case GLFW_KEY_F3:
    return "F3";
case GLFW_KEY_F4:
    return "F4";
case GLFW_KEY_F5:
    return "F5";
case GLFW_KEY_F6:
    return "F6";
case GLFW_KEY_F7:
    return "F7";
case GLFW_KEY_F8:
    return "F8";
case GLFW_KEY_F9:
    return "F9";
case GLFW_KEY_F10:
    return "F10";
case GLFW_KEY_F11:
    return "F11";
case GLFW_KEY_F12:
    return "F12";
case GLFW_KEY_F13:
    return "F13";
case GLFW_KEY_F14:
    return "F14";
case GLFW_KEY_F15:
    return "F15";
case GLFW_KEY_F16:
    return "F16";
case GLFW_KEY_F17:
    return "F17";
case GLFW_KEY_F18:
    return "F18";
case GLFW_KEY_F19:
    return "F19";
case GLFW_KEY_F20:
    return "F20";
case GLFW_KEY_F21:
    return "F21";
case GLFW_KEY_F22:
    return "F22";
case GLFW_KEY_F23:
    return "F23";
case GLFW_KEY_F24:
    return "F24";
case GLFW_KEY_F25:
    return "F25";

case GLFW_KEY_KP_0:
    return "KeyPad 0";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_1:
    return "KeyPad 1";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_2:
    return "KeyPad 2";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_3:
    return "KeyPad 3";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_4:
    return "KeyPad 4";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_5:
    return "KeyPad 5";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_6:
    return "KeyPad 6";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_7:
    return "KeyPad 7";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_8:
    return "KeyPad 8";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_9:
    return "KeyPad 9";

case GLFW_KEY_KP_DECIMAL:
    return "KeyPad Decimal";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_DIVIDE:
    return "KeyPad Divide";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_MULTIPLY:
    return "KeyPad Multiply";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_SUBTRACT:
    return "KeyPad Subtract";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_ADD:
    return "KeyPad Add";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_ENTER:
    return "KeyPad Enter";
case GLFW_KEY_KP_EQUAL:
    return "KeyPad Equal";

case GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT:
    return "Left Shift";
case GLFW_KEY_LEFT_CONTROL:
    return "Left Control";
case GLFW_KEY_LEFT_ALT:
    return "Left Alt";
case GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SUPER:
    return "Left Super";

case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT:
    return "Right Shift";
case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT_CONTROL:
    return "Right Control";
case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT_ALT:
    return "Right Alt";
case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT_SUPER:
    return "Right Super";

case GLFW_KEY_MENU:
    return "Menu";
default:
    return "Unknown key!";
}
}

Заранее спасибо :)

glfwGetKeyName.
Только имейте ввиду, что буквенные клавиши, не отображаются, кроме английского ,там нужно читать scan code
Читайте документацию.
https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__input.html#gaeaed62e69c3bd62b7ff8f7b19913ce4f
